# onNotificationPosted method not called even when the app is running in foreground

Tags: android

I'm doing an application where I'll capture all the notifications and save it in my app. I am using `BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` service and I have created a class extending `NotificationListenerService` for the same.

I have specified necessary permissions, services in the `Manifest` file.

I have specified `return START_STICKY` in the `onStartCommand()` function in NotificationListener service class.

---

**Problem**: (Device - Redmi Note 5 Pro)

`onNotificationPosted()` function works only for 10 to 15 minutes after installation. After 15 minutes, When I close and re-open it again, **even when the app is open on the screen (Foreground)**, `onNotificationPosted()` doesn't get called while receiving notifications. I tried triggering the service manually and when I do that, `onStartCommand()` gets called but `onNotificationPosted()` doesn't work after that also.

I checked the services running list and I found my app's package name in the list. Hence, service is up and running but no behaving as expected.

**Expected Behaviour**
`onNotificationPosted()` should get called while receiving notification at least after triggering it manually.

I can understand android will kill the service for performance while running in the background. Why it doesn't work even when the app is in the foreground. Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

Thanks for the time.. (:

Comment: Ganesh Any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no brother. Lemme know in comments if you find the solution in future. Best of luck.